# Python print server

Tags: python, printing

I'm trying to find a solution to create a print server that Windows users can print to and format what they print to XML.

I found this python script: http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/rawprintserver.html (download on right hand side; vertically). Upon installing and testing it out, it seems to be getting the print job. However, every time I try to print to it, it just logs "Error: lpr returns 100" and exits.

Here is the full log:

```
[2011/11/08 11:51:51] Raw Print Server Startup: PID = 16998
[2011/11/08 11:51:51] Starting Printer <dotmatrix> on port 9100
[2011/11/08 11:51:51] Starting Printer <dotmatrix> on port 9101
[2011/11/08 11:52:01] Receiving Job from ('192.168.1.19', 49448) for Printer <dotmatrix> (Spool File RawPrintJob00001.prn) 
[2011/11/08 11:52:01] Printer <dotmatrix>: Printing Job RawPrintJob00001.prn
[2011/11/08 11:52:01] Error: lpr returns 100
```

I followed the readme to the letter so spool is in /var/tmp as opposed to cups spool, if that matters.

I don't see that error in any of the files, and looking for python error code 100 doesn't help.

Perhaps someone can let me know what that error means.. OR, perhaps a python guru could just take a cursory look at the code (small, ~6 files ~100 lines each) and let me know where I can tap into the output/whichermercallit so I can start learning how to work with XML in python :)

It doesn't seem to leave a prn file anywhere. Really, all I need is to generate a text file or somesuch from the print job which I can then modify. However, a more elegant solution is welcome (e.g. a way to modify the stream/job before writing to file).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `spooler.py` file contains this snippet of code:

```
class printer(base_printer):
    def sendjob(self, fp, title = None):
        # title is irrelevant here
        out = os.popen("lpr -P'%s' >/dev/null 2>&1" \
            % self.printer_name, "wb")
        blk = fp.read(8192)
        while blk:
            out.write(blk)
            blk = fp.read(8192)
        rc = out.close()
        if rc is not None:
            print "Error: lpr returns %02x" % rc
```

so, the script is using `popen()` in order to launch an `lpr` job. the error you encounter is probably due to a misconfiguration of lpr. try using the exact same command from your command line shell and see how it works.

Comment: Well I can't run the exact command as the arguments aren't there. I also don't have a printer hooked up (don't want to) so don't know if it completes (must ctrl-c to cancel) but lpr -P /tmp/file.txt throws no errors. Also, os.popen seems to work as expected ">>> os.popen("/tmp/file.txt")
<open file '/tmp/file.txt', mode 'r' at 0x2ac57084b828>" However, this is the file/code I needed to find. I was able to set it to write the print job to a file--I will try and get it to work from there. Thanks!